# i'm trying to solve an algorithm with java and i find some issue

Tags: java, algorithm

i'm taring convert this to a Java program :

```
$ java SpaceTravel
Welcome to the SpaceTravel agency
What do you want do? [h for help]
a
Unknown command. Type h for help
What do you want do? [h for help]
h
h: print this help screen
q: quit the program
What do you want do? [h for help]
q
Bye bye!
```

Now the problem that my program seem's do an infinite loop at the 2nd `do while` loop whatever is my choice i tried many algorithm's and steel wont work for me . here is my code :

```
package gesitionEleve;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class SpaceTravel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Welcom to the SpaceTravel Agency\n");


        int lafin = 0;

        while (lafin != 1) {

            int taill;
            do {
                System.out.print("What do you want to do [h for help] : ");
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                String test = sc.nextLine();
                taill = test.length();
            } while(taill == 0);

            char choix = 0;

            String test;
            if (choix != 'h') {

                do {
                    System.out.print("\nUknown command. Type h for help ");
                    System.out.print("\nWhat do you want to do : ");
                    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    test = sc1.nextLine();
                    choix = test.charAt(0);
                } while(choix == 'h');

            }

            System.out.print("\nh : print this help page ");
            System.out.print("\nq : quite the program ");                       

            do {
                Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        test = sc1.nextLine();
                        choix = test.charAt(0);

                        switch(choix) {
                            case 'h' : 
                            System.out.print("\nh : print this help page ");
                            System.out.print("\nq : quite the program ");
                            case 'q' : 
                            System.out.print("Bye bye");
                            lafin++;
                        }
            } while (choix == 'q' || choix == 'h');
        }

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below program suits your needs:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SpaceTravel
{
      public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Welcome to the SpaceTravel Agency\n");

        String str; //To avoid exception when user enters just an enter

        while (true) { //infinite loop

          char choix; //for getting a character

            System.out.print("What do you want to do [h for help] : ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            str=sc.nextLine();  //get input
            if(str.length()!=1) //If no characters or more than one character is entered,
            {
              System.out.println("Invalid Choice");
              continue;
            }
            choix=str.charAt(0); //get char from str

          if(choix=='q') //if char is q,break out of the while loop
              break;  
          if (choix != 'h') { //if char is not h,print invalid input and continue the loop

              System.out.println("\nUnknown command. Type h for help ");
              continue;

          }

          System.out.print("\nh : print this help page ");
          System.out.print("\nq : quit the program ");           

        }

      } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the condition of that loop backwards.

If you want to leave the loop when 'h' is entered, it should be :

```
            do {
                System.out.print("\nUknown command. Type h for help ");
                System.out.print("\nWhat do you want to do : ");
                Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                test = sc1.nextLine();
                choix = test.charAt(0);
            } while(choix != 'h');
```

Currently you are staying in the loop as long as 'h' is entered.

You should also note that `test.charAt(0)` would throw an exception if the user presses enter without typing any characters.